# Not all apps are showing in folder while in recovery mode.....please help

Tags: macbook-pro

How do I find a mail application that I installed on my Mac, while running in recovery mode ?

Comment: When you say recovery mode, do you mean you rebooted and held "cmd r"? How are you trying to find this application? finder? Terminal?

Comment: When in Recovery Mode, you are booting from a *different* volume than you normally do.  Your mail app, data, etc. will be on the normal boot volume.   That said, this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Consider editing your question to describe the *initial* issue that is causing you to look for this particular solution.